# At what point in the Star Wars timeline did this character become a parent?

Tags: star-wars, the-rise-of-skywalker

Judging from Luke and Leia's birth, procreation in the Star Wars universe works basically as we'd expect on Earth (but with robot midwives).  Having now learned that...

> Rey, I am your grandfather
>  -- Darth Sidious

...I'm puzzled as to when they procreated.  I don't recall seeing evidence of them even having a prior relationship nor having a family.  It's also a bit hard for me to imagine this character finding a partner, having sex<sup>(*)</sup>, parenting, etc.

**Question**: At what point in the Star Wars timeline did this character become a parent?

I'm perplexed as to where it fits into the Star Wars timeline, especially:

> Did pre-resurrection or post-resurrection Darth Sidious become a parent?

<sub><sup>(*)</sup> Apologies for the mental image.</sub>

Comment: I find it equally perplexing that the child would oppose them. With everything the parent has accomplished it seems implausible that they couldn't raise their own child to follow in their footsteps.

Comment: I find it hard to understand why it seems implausible that powerful government officials in a dark grim corrupt universe such as warhamm- i mean star wars arn’t banging  space hookers everyday?

Answer (score 1):

When we first see

> Sheev Palpatine

In The Phantom Menace, he is already old enough (50ish) to have had a family, so not impossible for him for having one or more childs.

Answer (score 1):

[This discusses events in older *Star Wars* movies without spoiler space.  Spoiler space is used for *The Rise of Skywalker* spoilers.]

#### When was Rey born?

From Wookiepedia, I'm piecing this together:

> *Star Wars: The Force Awakens: The Visual Dictionary* states that Rey is nineteen years old during the events of *Star Wars: Episode VII The Force Awakens*, which is dated to 34 ABY by *Star Wars: Galactic Atlas*. Therefore it can be deduced that ***Rey was born in 15 ABY = 19 BSI***.
> <sub>[15 ABY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/15_ABY#cite_note-Rey_date-1)</sub>

Using Wookiepedia's terminology, [15 ABY](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/15_ABY) = 19 BSI = 19 years before the Starkiller Incident, i.e., 13 years before e.g. the Starkiller base was destroyed.

#### Let's subtract say 30 years, to estimate when her parents were born.

Thus it's probably a reasonable guess that Rey's parents were born somewhere around 50 BSI.  It likely Rey and her parents and grandparents are all [humans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Human).  Wookiepedia has a [useful timetable](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Unidentified_calendar) which lists:

> 53 BSI: End of the Clone Wars and transformation of the Republic into the Galactic Empire. Anakin Skywalker becomes Darth Vader.

This is probably in the ballpark (maybe +/- 15 years) of when...

> ...[Rey's father](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rey%27s_father) was born.  So pre-resurrection Darth Sidious had a son, Rey's father.

So it probably happened somewhere during the prequel trilogy.